# Getting the index path of collection view cell inside separate method in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button inside my collection view cell to save the item at index path to an array property in parse's user class. The collection view is populated by events and the user clicks a button which pops an alert view and when they click yes the event will be saved to an array of events the user will be attending.

Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I add a target to the button and call the pop alert view method which is all fine and good...

```
cell.attendButton.addTarget(self, action: "popAlertView", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Now inside the method is where I'm running into some problems...

There is an error on the second line of the method (let event...) that says that "any object does not have a member named row". What's the best way to access the index path and instantiate the event for the respective one?

```
func popAlertView() {

    var indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    let event = events[indexPath?.row]

    var alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: "Attend event?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertViewController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in



        // save event to array of events of user
    }))

    alertViewController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in


    }))

    self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in

        // finish up here
    }
}
```

Also, in the save event to the array of events (user class) how exactly can I go about that, both saving and retrieving objects of PFUser.currentUser in array form? I looked on Parse's developers guide but couldn't find much to help me out with that specifically, only saving single objects.

I'm pretty new to swift and parse so thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

[`indexPathsForSelectedItems()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForSelectedItems) returns `[NSIndexPath]?`, meaning a Swift `Optional Array` of `NSIndexPath` objects.

In order to get at the actual `NSIndexPath` objects, you'll need to first unwrap the `Optional`, and then iterate through the `Array`. In this case, let's use a `guard` since we can't proceed unless there's at least one `NSIndexPath`.

```
guard let selectedItemPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() else { return }

var selectedEvents = [Event]()
for indexPath in selectedItemPaths {
    selectedEvents.append(events[indexPath.row])
}
```

At that point you'd have an `Array` of your `Event` objects based on all off the `selectedItems`. Assuming you were clearing the selected paths every time the user adds one, you'd only be adding one `Event` every time this code is called.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried this but get an error on the selected events.append line... 

"immutable value of type "event" only has mutating members name "append"

Comment: Echizzle: try it now, I made the array a `let` variable, but it should be a `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the target, use @IBAction like this

```
@IBAction func popAlertView(sender: AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    if indexPath != nil {
        let cell:SweetTableViewCell!(change this) = tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! SweetTableViewCell!(change this too)
```

Comment: I tried this too but it didn't work for a collection view